# Linker error while compiling GCC 8.2.0 related to libmpfr.so

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mpfr

I'm trying to compile GCC from scratch like I used to do when I used Linux a lot, I'm trying to install Sourcemage but the compiler version of GCC is 4.6 and the latest version is 8.2.0, so I compiled everything needed to compile GCC from scratch, and everything is going well while compiling the compiler until the very end when it starts giving me a linker error related to libmpfr.so:
Here's what I get when I do my typical make -j3:

```
/usr/lib/../lib/libmpfr.so: undefined reference to `__gmpn_com'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../.././gcc/lto/Make-lang.in:81: lto1] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/lib/../lib/libmpfr.so: undefined reference to `__gmpn_com'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../.././gcc/c/Make-lang.in:85: cc1] Error 1
/usr/lib/../lib/libmpfr.so: undefined reference to `__gmpn_com'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../.././gcc/cp/Make-lang.in:120: cc1plus] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4657: all-stage2-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:22203: stage2-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:944: all] Error 2
```

If you want to look at the full output of the error then I provide a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/g5sn3jDv

Comment: Having compiled gcc before, a long time ago, there isn't, unfortunately, a magic button one can push to make this linking error go away. If i were doing this, my next step would be to figure out which library defines this symbol -- whether something that gets installed by gcc, or an existing system library -- and then pour through gcc's build script and makefile in order to figure out why it's not being linked correctly. That's what you'll have to do, and, the only thing I can say: good luck.

Comment: are you sure you installed all required dependencies to build gcc? it seems like `libgmp` might be missing...

Comment: Oddly enough, I tried reinstalling libgmp from source (Might have forgotten that beforehand) and I also added --disable-bootstrap to the configuration so not only was it much faster to compile the thing but it also worked, but I have no clue what triggered it to work, my best guess is that I missed libgmp rather than the --disable-bootstrap option, either ways thank you

Comment: Your pastebin doesn't contain any error. But it seems that your GMP was much too old and did not provide `mpn_com`, which is needed by MPFR. If `libgmp` was simply missing (or not found), you would have got an error earlier. Actually that's strange, because there's a check of the GMP version in MPFR's `configure.ac`.